# How do I not show duplicate error when using mysqli

Tags: php, database, mysqli, error-handling

I am using the code below to input transactions into a database.  Each transaction has a unique "id" associated with it, so in phpMyAdmin, I declared the "id" field (actually called transaction_id in my database) to be a unique value, thus preventing duplicates.  Now when I download the transaction data into the database, it only adds in new transactions.

This causes a large amount of duplicate errors:

```
*Error: INSERT INTO Transactions (id, transaction_id ... Duplicate entry '#############' for key 'transaction_id'*
```

I'd like to show all errors except the duplicate error.  Is there a way to simply add this with an else if or into the else statement below?

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: You could use a select before insert to check if the record already exists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys. Here's what I came up with:

`if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { 
echo "New record created successfully"; 
} else if(mysqli_errno($conn) !== 1062) { 
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); }`

Answer (score 0):

> Jepf:

You can use the **mysqli-error** function, in order to retrieve the error code: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Afterwards, if the error code is **1586**, you could add a condition if the error code matches this value.

Here you have the the reference for Mysql error messages: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the duplicate, you could just use a select query to check for existence and then not perform the insert.

Alternatively, there is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

The insert on duplicate clause allows you to update a record if it exists, but insert if it doesn't.

*Obligatory note: stop using mysqli and start using pdo*